# Adicionar elementos em lista durante um loop em Python retorna sempre o mesmo valor

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
current = [0, 1]
someList = []

while True:
  for n in range(0, 2):
    current[n] += 1

  print(current) # [1,2] and [2,3]
  someList.append(current)

  if current == [2, 3]:
    break

print(someList) # [[2,3], [2,3]]
```

A cada *loop* a variável `current` recebe +1 a cada item seu, quando o `current` chega ao valor `[2,3]` o *loop* pára. O suposto era o `someList` ter um valor de `[[1,2], [2,3]]` mas acaba sempre com o ultimo valor de `current`, ou seja, acabou com `[[2,3], [2,3]]`. Por que que isto acontece?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque ao fazer `append(current)` você não está acrescentando um novo objeto à lista e sim a referência do mesmo objeto.

Quando você cria uma lista e atribui ela para uma variável, o que você atribuiu foi o endereço de memória para o objeto criado. Para comprovar isto, podemos fazer este teste:

```
lista1 = [1,2,3]
lista2 = lista1
lista2.clear()
print(lista1) # Saída: []
```

*E como então gerar uma cópia do objeto ?*

Podemos utilizar o método `copy()`. Este método irá criar e retornar um novo objeto com os mesmos dados do objeto original. Logo, seu código corrigido fica assim:

```
current = [0, 1]
someList = []

while True:
  for n in range(0, 2):
    current[n] += 1

  print(current) # [1,2] and [2,3]
  someList.append(current.copy())

  if current == [2, 3]:
    break

print(someList) # [[1,3], [2,3]]
```

Se você ainda não entendeu muito bem sobre isso tudo que eu falei, que tal pesquisar um pouco por "variáveis de referência" ? Aqui neste [site](https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/variaveis-valores-e-referencias/) você pode saber um pouco mais sobre esse assunto.

Answer (score 5):

Uma lista é um tipo com semântica por referência e não por valor, o que vocês está adicionando ao `someList` com o `append()` é uma referência para `current`. A referência de `current` não muda em momento algum então nas duas vezes que adiciona algo está adicionando o mesmo valor. Quando manda imprimir ele pega o valor que está sendo referenciado naquele momento, e ele é `[2, 3]` portanto ele aparece duas vezes. Não há mais o valor anterior em `current`, depois que você mudou o valor dele o antigo não existe mais, como qualquer variável já que ali é um valor.

Então para solucionar precisa ter referências diferentes fazendo uma clonagem da lista criando outra lista separada que não tem nenhuma outra referência para ela que possa afetar seu valor (isto pode ter efeitos indesejáveis em certas situações ou tornar o código ineficiente em cenários mais pesados, então não pode usar ingenuamente, precisa entender bem o modelo de memória). Algo assim (tem outras formas) soluciona:

```
current = [0, 1]
someList = []
while True:
    for n in range(0, 2):
        current[n] += 1
    print(current)
    someList.append(current[:])
    if current == [2, 3]:
        break
print(someList)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uotbtP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CloneListpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/CloneList.py).

Seria bom entender [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Em Python tem algum complicador a mais mas é isso.